# Get type info of struct fields when struct is serde::Serialize

Tags: rust, serde

I'm coding a local relational database system for some reason. I wanted to lean on serde for automatically converting some hashmaps to and from tables. The goal is to take hashmaps over simple types like:

```
struct SampleObject {
    name: String,
    age : Option<u32>,
    job : Option<String>
}
```

and create some function like:

```
pub fn from_serde_map<V>(
        table_name: &str,
        primary_key_name: &str,
        data: HashMap<String, V>,
    ) -> Result<Table>
    where
        V: Serialize,
```

which would use the functionality of `serde::Value` to convert the struct to a table over its fields. Notably the table needs type information and constraints on the column, and "NOT_NULL" constraints would be applied to all fields that were not optional in the underlying struct.

The sample struct above shows almost everything I expect to want from this - I don't need to support all rust types, all `Serialize` types or even any particularly broad range of types. The only things I need are flat structs over:

- Simple numeric types
- Strings
- Booleans
- Option of the other types on this list
- (Reach goal) `Vec<String>`
- (Reach goal) Simple Enums
- (Reach goal) `Vec<Simple Enum>`

My first stab at this just looked at the first item in the passed map and tries to construct a header out of it (basically just exploration):

```
use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};

#[derive(Debug, PartialEq, Eq, Hash, Clone, Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct SampleObject {
    name: String,
    age : Option<u32>,
    job : Option<String>
}
pub fn explore_item<V>(
    v : V
)
where
    V: Serialize,
{
    let header_object = serde_json::to_value(v)
        .unwrap()
        .as_object()
        .unwrap()
        .clone();
    for (k, v) in header_object.into_iter() {
        let as_value = serde_json::to_value(v).unwrap();
        println!("{}: {:?}", k, as_value);
    }
}
#[test]
fn call_explore_item() {
    let adam = SampleObject {
        name: "Adam".to_string(),
        age: None,
        job : Some("Gardener".to_string())
    }
    ;
    explore_item(adam);
}
```

This outputs the following:

```
age: Null
job: String("Gardener")
name: String("Adam")
```

There are a couple problems here:

- This requires an actual instance of `V`, which may not be present - it would be nice to be able to call this with, for instance, an empty map.
- `Option`-typed items lack type information; the fields for `job` and `name` show the same info despite one being Option-wrapped, and the `None` age field doesn't indicate it's a `u32` None as opposed to a `String` or whatever `None`.

I was hoping that I could do something like `(V as Serialize)::typeAt("crime")` and get some representation of the type information stored there, but no such luck.

I've looked at a couple json_schema crates, but support seems a little spotty and I imagine those may be trying to do a lot more ambitious things than I am. I'm wondering if there isn't an easier approach? Or is today finally the day I need to learn to write my own derive macros?

**EDIT FOR CLARIFICATION**

Specifically, I want to take a simple struct type like `SampleObject` and be able to get the types of each field, so long as the record only has fields of fairly simple types. I want this so that I can generate header information for my table.

So I would have some enum like `ColType` with variants for `StringType`, `u32Type`, etc. For `SampleObject`, I'd like the map to ultimately have three columns:

- `name` with `StringType` and `NotNull` constraint
- `age` with `U32Type`
- `job` with `StringType`

(`name` gets the `NotNull` constraint because the field isn't of `Option` type.)

Comment: Please reduce your example to be a [mre] I'm fairly certain your `data` does not need to be a `HashMap` to talk about and explain your problem and it makes this much more difficult, also `Self` can probably be removed as well (else you'd have to add it's definition).

Comment: @cafce25 Simplified the example - hoping the hashmap context speaks to the issue of possibly calling this with an empty collection, or that the context in general may highlight XY problems

Comment: This sounds very much like you need your own trait and corresponding derive macro.

Comment: that a very weird use of serde, you should code your serializer properly at this point.

Comment: @Stargateur Can you elaborate? I think last time I asked about something similar (wanting to iterate over struct fields) `serde` was the suggestion, and it seems good save for the type issue..

Comment: https://serde.rs/impl-serializer.html

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do. From your description it sounds like you want to serialize a `HashMap<String, serde_json::Value>` as `Table`, but this isn't what your code does.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Not quite - the hashmap shouldn't be to `serde_json::Value` but to `V: Serialize`. The example at the bottom (I was asked to reduce it to a more minimal MRE) shows how I don't see sufficient type information coming out of `serde`. What I want is enough information to give a schema/header for my table based on the struct - so, the type of data in each column, and which (if any) types are `Option`. (Editing some more into my original question)

Comment: Then I don't understand why any of the existing schema crates isn't good for you, for example [`schemars`](https://docs.rs/schemars/).

Comment: @ChayimFriedman that might be the right approach - just felt like I was wandering further onto a limb, and that there might be simpler options I was missing entirely, especially because `schemars` seems somewhat small and niche for what seems like a common problem (trying to get data about a type).

Comment: I will argue it's not a common problem. The more common cases where this problem manifests is getting schema of API etc., which schemars fills.